# HP intelligent provisioning failed to start

Tags: hp, hp-proliant

Upgrading HP Intelligent provisioning(IP), the system turned off. After that I couldn't start IP using `F10`, I've tried to re-install/upgrade it via CD-ROM (according to HP trouble shooting website), the process ends successfully but still noway to start intelligent provisioning and it restarts the system.

How can I make IP start after pressing `F10`? for example any way to reset to factory?

Comment: What happens when you press `F10` during POST? What model of server are you using? And what version of Intelligent Provisioning did you load?

Comment: Server is HP proliant DL380p gen8 v2, IP version was 1.6 upgraded to the latest 1.61, when I press `F10` there are 2 beep and black display then the progress of IP loading is shown and when it is complete, again black display and system restarts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through this:

[HP ProLiant Gen8 and Gen9 Servers - How to Install/Reinstall Intelligent Provisioning (IP) if It Does Not Launch After Pressing F10 During Power-On Self-Test (POST)](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c04957054&docLocale=en_US)

But I didn't have any success with the latest version, 1.61.

Finally I decided to downgrade it to 1.5 version and that worked.
After that I installed version 1.61 and still working fine.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't encountered this before, but I did receive a random call and email from HP support last month informing that they would be sending me instructions on how to reinstall and upgrade the [Intelligent Provisioning](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5219984) software:

> Dear Valued Customer: ￼This letter is in response to your request for
>   instructions to re-install HP Intelligent Provisioning (IP) on HP
>   ProLiant Gen8-series servers, Storage and Networking products.
>   Instructions to create a bootable DVD with the IP image are provided
>   on the HP Intelligent Provisioning recovery media download site under
>   the Installation Instructions tab. Note: The DVD can be used multiple
>   times and on all HP ProLiant Gen8-series servers, Storage and
>   Networking products. HP Intelligent Provisioning recovery media
>   Version 1.61 (16 Sep 2014):
>   https://www.hp.com/swpublishing/MTX-b23c0288447c48afa543a41de9
>
> Please
>   note the Intelligent Provisioning Recovery Media DVD may be remotely
>   mounted using iLO Virtual Media functionality, in order to reinstall
>   Intelligent Provisioning. Additional information is available in the
>   Integrated Lights-Out iLO4 User Guide at the following URL regarding
>   how to mount an ISO image (federated or un-federated) and perform
>   basic virtual media operations. Reference Pages 189 and 223-237.
>   http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c03334051-11.pdf

I also hope that your Intelligent Provisioning is [actually enabled](https://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=mmr_kc-0108654) in the BIOS...

You don't see something like this, do you?

[image]

If so:

- Press F9 during POST for RBSU.
- Choose Server Security -> Intelligent Provisioning (F10 Prompt) -> Enable
- Save changes and Exit RBSU.
- Reboot.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, but intelligent provisioning was already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case it helps anyone, I was getting "Error flashing the nvram" trying to reinstall Intelligent Provisioning on a DL380p Gen 8 (latest BIOS and ILO firmware installed), using any of the recovery ISO images. Resetting the nvram in hardware or software made no difference and no errors were reported in the ILO pages. In the end, I was able to get it installed by booting into a Linux OS and running the rpm package as described here. The Linux package worked for me where everything else had failed...
https://www.hpe.com/psnow/resources/ebooks/a00112754en_us_v2/s_reinstalling_from_rpm.html